# Sentiment analysis with python

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do sentiment analysis with python.I have gone through various tutorials and have used libraries like nltk, textblob etc for it.

But what I want is bit different and I am not able figure out any material for that

Suppose I have a statement like

```
apples are tasty but they are very expensive
```

The above statement can be classified in to two classes/labels like **taste** and  **money**

My aim is to get sentiment of the statement with respect to these two labels

My expected result would be **positive** sentiment for **taste** but **negative** sentiment for **money**

How this can be achieved

With textblob

```
def calculate_sentiment_textblob(current_comment):
current_comment = str(current_comment)

comment_sentiment_calculation = TextBlob(current_comment)

comment_sentiment = ""

if comment_sentiment_calculation.sentiment.polarity < 0:
    comment_sentiment = "Negative"
elif comment_sentiment_calculation.sentiment.polarity > 0:
    comment_sentiment = "Positive"
else:
    comment_sentiment = "Neutral"

print(current_comment)
print(comment_sentiment)
sentiment_list.append(current_comment +" "+comment_sentiment)
comments_scraped.loc[comments_scraped.reviews== current_comment,'sentiment_textblob'] = comment_sentiment
```

With vader

```
def calculate_sentiment_vader(current_comment):
    current_comment = str(current_comment)

    comment_sentiment_calculation = sid.polarity_scores(current_comment)

    comment_sentiment = ""

    if comment_sentiment_calculation['compound'] < 0:
        comment_sentiment = "Negative"
    elif comment_sentiment_calculation['compound'] > 0:
        comment_sentiment = "Positive"
    else:
        comment_sentiment = "Neutral"

    comments_scraped.loc[comments_scraped.reviews== current_comment,'sentiment_vader'] = comment_sentiment
```

Comment: Let's see the code you've tried so far

Comment: Sure I can upload the one which was tried with vader and textblob

Comment: @JacobIRR Added code for textblob and vader

Comment: Did you have any progress @Rookie_123?

Comment: I am extremely sorry But no progress so far.I have tried different resources available but no satisfactory result so far

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest you investigate on aspect-based sentiment analysis. It does not focus sentiment on only an entity but an entity's attributes. There have been SemEval challenges to investigate this problem on attributes of entities, for example laptops and restaurants.

There were many participants, their papers are published and the organizers published explanatory papers as well.

You can reach them here:

- http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2014/task4/
- http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/task12/
- http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task5/

Hope these help, cheers.